# Image stretching inside ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to show couple of image in a viewPager. The images are showing fine in landscape mode but in portrait mode images are stretching.

Here is my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.helloExp.builder.BuilderActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/builder_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Swipe to change image"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="When one door of happiness closes, another opens; but often we look so long at the closed door that we do not see the one that has opened for us."
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Decoration"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="Share"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my viewPager adapter xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/cat_life_big"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally here is the Adapter code:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_builder, container, false);
        container.addView(layoutView);
        return layoutView;
    }
```

See the output

Portrait - See the image is stretching here.

[image]

Landscape

[image]

Comment: Use glide to load images in image view.

Comment: They will stretch because original image aspect ratio is around 16:9 and your portrait mode will have opposite aspect ratio. One get around is use    android:scaleType="centerCrop" in your imageview

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with `android:scaleType="fitCenter`

Try `android:scaleType:"center_crop"` and see what it does.

Also from [Android developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html), you see that `CENTER` does no do scalling...and `FIT_CENTER` is based on `CENTER`

Answer (score 0):

use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

**[CENTER_CROP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)**

Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

try this make your `ImageView` like this

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@drawable/cat_life_big"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: @JasonKrs than congratulation

Comment: Hey @NileshRathod, no luck brother. Just to mention ImageView is wrapped inside a LinearLayout which has wrap content for height and width.

Comment: Actually I was working on a project few weeks ago.. that's why it was obvious at first sight... I'm no expert.

Comment: @TechBee try to set programatically imageView.setScaleType(CENTER_CROP) or   imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the scaleType attribute. Depending on your needs you could use either "centerCrop" or "centerInside". Both cases will fit both axes very well, while the one you are currently using fits only one. You can also find more info on this by reaching:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Answer (score 0):

chage your imageview code. your are using image as bacground change it to src.
your code is

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/cat_life_big"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

change it to

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/cat_life_big"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh. No luck brother.